# Why, for $f(n) = n \cdot \sqrt n$ and $g(n)=n^2/\log n$, we have $f(n) = o(g(n))$?

Tags: big-o-notation

Let $f(n) = n \cdot \sqrt n$ and $g(n)= \frac{n^2}{\log n}$.  Why is $f(n) = o(g(n))$?

Could you please explain to me why this is so?  I have tried l'Hôpital's rule but it doesn't add any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(n) = n^{1.5}$ and $g(n) = n^2/\log n$.

Note that $\log n$ grows slower than any polynomial function.

Try to compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

Which grows faster, $\log n$ or $\sqrt n$?

---

More details: By dividing by $n^{1.5}$, we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1.5}}{n^2/\log n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n/\log n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}$$

It should be quite clear that this limit is 0, but if not, you may see that both of them go to $+\infty$, and you may use l'Hôpital's rule and you get $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n'}{\sqrt n'} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c/n}{1.5} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2c}{3n}$$
for some $c$ depending on the base of your logarithm.

Now, it is the case that $f(n) = o(g(n))$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$, which is the case here.

Comment: Ok, I see now. It is simpler than I thought. Thank you very much for your clarifiction.

Comment: I have one more question. Wll the lim approaches infinity, how can I determine that f(n) = Ω(g(n)) or f(n) =ω(g)

Comment: $\lim f/g = 0$ if and only if $f = o(g)$.  See [little-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)

Comment: It seem to mee that I am stuck on computing the ration? Should I use l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Hmmm. Still confused with the second part. d/dx off log(n) is 1/xln2, right?

Comment: I think at this point, you're on your own.  The provided answer should be enough to solve the problem.  The remaining parts are just calculations that are not really computer science.  You can choose to mark the answer as correct if you wish, as well as vote up or down.